# Tabitem Header's button name from code behind

Tags: wpf, vb.net, wpf-controls, tabitem

I have a `TabControl`, and I am adding `TabItem`s dynamically to it . I have a predefined `DataTemplate` in the `TabControl`'s resources.  So, there is a `TextBox` and a `Button` in that template. I bind that template with the `TabItem` dynamically and add that tab item to tab control.

Here is the code :

```
    <Window x:Class="Menu"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="tab" Height="465" Width="869">
    <Window.Resources>

    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
    <TabControl Name="tab" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" verticalAlignment="Top"  >
        <TabControl.Resources  >
            <DataTemplate x:Key="TabHead" DataType="TabItem" >
                <WrapPanel >
                    <Label Name="lbl1" Content="tab1" ></Label>
                    <Button Name="btn1" Content="X"></Button>
                </WrapPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.Resources>


        </TabControl>
       <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="55,246,0,0" Name="Button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
      </Grid>
     </Window>
```

this is XAML code and here is VB.NET code :

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim tabi As New TabItem
    tabi.HeaderTemplate = TryCast(tab.Resources("TabHead"), DataTemplate)
    tab.Items.Add(tabi)

    End Sub
```

Now I want to have a unique name for each button which is in the `DataTemplate` of the `TabControl`'s resources.

How can I set unique names for each `Button` in my `DataTemplate`?

Comment: Don't manipulate UI elements in procedural code in WPF. That's what XAML is for. Create a proper ViewModel and use DataBinding for this.

Comment: can u please give me an example .... pleaseeee